# Conditional Concatenation Based on String Value in Column

Tags: python, string, pandas

The python data frame I currently have contains two columns: "EVENT" and "NAME".

```
EVENT   NAME
A       DEN
B       HAU
C       TOT
D       ABC
E       DEN
```

I want to implement logic so that my EVENT column is as follows:

```
EVENT
A_DEN
B
C
D
E_DEN
```

I want to implement logic that says if "NAME" column contains DEN value then concatenate it to the value in "EVENT" column.  Otherwise, leave value as is in "EVENT" column.

I have scoured the internet on how to do this but wasn't able to find anything specific to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Option 1**
You could do this with `str.contains`/`eq` to perform the "contains" check, and `np.where` to conditionally build your result -

```
df.EVENT = np.where(df.NAME.str.contains('DEN'), df.EVENT + '_' + df.NAME, df.EVENT)
```

Or,

```
df.EVENT = np.where(df.NAME.eq('DEN'), df.EVENT + '_' + df.NAME, df.EVENT)
```

```
df

   EVENT NAME
0  A_DEN  DEN
1      B  HAU
2      C  TOT
3      D  ABC
4  E_DEN  DEN
```

Don't forget to `import numpy as np`.

---

**Option 2**
Another method is using `pd.Series.mask`/`pd.Series.where` -

```
df.EVENT = df.EVENT.mask(df.NAME.str.contains('DEN'), df.EVENT + '_' + df.NAME)
```

Or,

```
df.EVENT = df.EVENT.where(~df.NAME.str.contains('DEN'), df.EVENT + '_' + df.NAME)
```

```
df

   EVENT NAME
0  A_DEN  DEN
1      B  HAU
2      C  TOT
3      D  ABC
4  E_DEN  DEN
```

---

**Option 3**
Yet another option is using `loc` based indexing with a mask -

```
m = df.NAME.str.contains('DEN')
df.loc[m, 'EVENT'] += ('_' + df.loc[m, 'NAME'])

df
   EVENT NAME
0  A_DEN  DEN
1      B  HAU
2      C  TOT
3      D  ABC
4  E_DEN  DEN
```

Comment: I was just going to post the one with np.where :)

Comment: @Vaishali `np.where` is usually the bread and butter for many pandas problems... easy to implement too, one of my favourite numpy functions :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Is it safe to use pd.np.where? or would importing np and np.where be more future proof?

Comment: @AntonvBR I think np.where would be safer, I use `pd.np` so op doesn't need to `import numpy as np` explicitly. Will edit.

Comment: thank you ... what if I want to add an additional condition ?  For example, concatenate only if NAME contains DEN and EVENT contains B

Comment: @PineNuts0 Condition becomes: `df.NAME.str.contains('DEN') & df.EVENT.str.contains('B')` everything else is the same.

Comment: df_adhoc_1['EVENT'] = np.where((df_adhoc_1['TRACKNAME'].str.contains('DEN') & df_adhoc_1['EVENT'].str.contains('GRCHG')), df_adhoc_1['EVENT']  + '_' + df_adhoc_1['TRACKNAME'], df_adhoc_1['EVENT'])

Comment: so above is my actual code ... the output file is not doing the concatenation ... any thoughts?

Comment: @PineNuts0 The syntax is correct, so I can only advise you to check your columns and data. Take out a small sample for which concatenation should occur, and see if it works for that sample or not.

Comment: it worked!  I removed the extra set of parenthesis I added in ... thank you so much for your detailed response!

Comment: I have an outstanding question regarding np.where that has bugged my mind for awhile.  What if you need to do multiple np.where statements?  For example, if in addition to my original code, I wanted to also do if NAME contains ASD then concatenate ... won't that re-write the column and remove the original np.where statement?

Comment: @PineNuts0 I'm not sure if I follow. `np.where` is basically a vectorised version of `if cond: x else: y` -> `np.where(cond, x, y)`. `cond` can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `loc` alternative with no mask.

```
df.loc[df['NAME'] == 'DEN', 'EVENT'] = df['EVENT'] + "_" + df['NAME']
```

```
df

   EVENT NAME
0  A_DEN  DEN
1      B  HAU
2      C  TOT
3      D  ABC
4  E_DEN  DEN
```

additional conditions can be easily added as follows:

```
df.loc[(df['NAME'] == 'DEN') | (df['NAME'] == 'HAU'), 'EVENT'] = df['EVENT'] + "_" + df['NAME']
```

```
df

   EVENT NAME
0  A_DEN  DEN
1  B_HAU  HAU
2      C  TOT
3      D  ABC
4  E_DEN  DEN
```